# Adding list in form of tuples to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Assuming there is a list with sublists like this

```
[[2013, 'Patric', 'M', 1356], [2013, 'Helena', 'F', 202], [2013, 'Patric', 'F', 6],[1993, 'Patric', 'F', 7]......]
```

which is an output of `def list_of_names()` where 2013 is year, M is gender and 1356 is number of M births etc.

And I want to create a dictionary which outputs the name as a key and values as tuples (year, number_of_males,number_of_females) . So for example:

```
{ .. ’Patric’:[... , (1993, 0, 7), (2013, 1356, 6), ... ], ... }.
```

Technically 1993 is year, 0 is number of males and 7 is number of females and the tuples should be arranged in order of the years.

and I'm stuck on how to add this info into a dictionary

```
def name_Index(names):
    d = dict()
    L = readNames() #the list with from previous def which outputs different names and info as above
    newlist = []
    for sublist in L:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def list_of_names():
    return [[2013, 'Patric', 'M', 1356],
            [2013, 'Helena', 'F', 202],
            [2013, 'Patric', 'F', 6],
            [1993, 'Patric', 'F', 7]]

def name_Index():
    tmp = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda: [0,0]))

    for year, name, sex, N in list_of_names():
        i = 0 if sex == 'M' else 1
        tmp[name][year][i] += N

    d = {}
    for name, entries in tmp.items():
        d[name] = [(year, M, F) for (year, (M,F)) in entries.items()]

    return d

print name_Index()
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my attempt at the problem:

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
from itertools import groupby

data = [[2013, 'Patric', 'M', 1356],
        [2013, 'Helena', 'F', 202],
        [2013, 'Patric', 'F', 6],
        [1993, 'Patric', 'F', 7]]

names = defaultdict(list)
datum = namedtuple('datum', 'year gender number')
for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[1]):
    for l in g:
        year, name, gender, number = l
        names[k].append(datum(year, gender, number))

final_dict = defaultdict(list)
for n in names:
    for k, g in groupby(names[n], lambda x: x.year):
        males = 0
        females = 0
        for l in g:
            if l.gender == 'M':
                males += l.number
            elif l.gender == 'F':
                females += l.number
        final_dict[n].append((k, males, females))

print(final_dict)
```

Comment: Man, it feels good to use `itertools` again. I still got it :)

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient will be to use `collections.defauldict`. It returns dictionary-like object, that returns default value, if it doesn't find key. In your case, you use a `list` as default value, and in your loop you append tuples to it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

names = [ [2013, 'Patric', 'M', 1356], 
        [2013, 'Helena', 'F', 202], 
        [2013, 'Patric', 'F', 6],
        [1993, 'Patric', 'F', 7]    ]

def name_Index(data):
    # name => year => sex
    d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: {'F': 0, 'M': 0})) 
    for year, name, sex, births in data:
        d[name][year][sex] += births

    # if you are fine with defauldict result: return d
    # else collect results into tuples:

    result = {}
    for name, data in d.items():
        result[name] = [(year, c['M'], c['F']) for year, c in data.items()]
    return result

    print name_Index(names)
    # {'Helena': [(2013, 0, 202)], 'Patric': [(1993, 0, 7), (2013, 1356, 6)]}
```

Comment: Supposedly your `readNames` returns / yields items from `lst`, but this is not (yet) in the code snippet.

Comment: nice catcht. stub added

Comment: This will not return what he's looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. But what the code is supposed to do is that take a list that consists of 500 or more sublists and create a dictionary. But with a different criteria. for instance from the above list (lst) Patric is the key and value should be [(1993, 0, 7), (2013, 1356, 202)..] so the tuple should take the number of males and females from the same year (year, male number,female number) and if there is no data for male it should be zero.

Comment: yes, I misunderstood what OP exactly wants. Now it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you are taking names as an argument of name_Index function and then calling readNames, there must be some necessity required for your work. Hence, i just put a dummy readNames function and sent None as argument to name_Index. Using class is a good technique to solve complicated data structures. Btw, nicely written question i must admit.

```
def readNames ():
    return [[2013, 'Patric', 'M', 1356], [2013, 'Helena', 'F', 202], [2013, 'Patric', 'F', 6],[1993, 'Patric', 'F', 7]]

class YearOb(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.male = 0
        self.female = 0

    def add_birth_data(self, gender, birth_count):
        if gender == "M":
            self.male += birth_count
        else:
            self.female += birth_count

class NameOb(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.yearobs = dict()

    def add_record(self, year, gender, birth_count):
        if year not in self.yearobs:
            self.yearobs[year]=YearOb()

        self.yearobs[year].add_birth_data(gender, birth_count)           

    def get_as_list(self):
        list_data = []
        for year, yearob in self.yearobs.items():
            list_data.append((year, yearob.male, yearob.female))
        return list_data

def name_Index(names):
    d = dict()
    L = readNames() #the list with from previous def which outputs different names and info as above
    newlist = []
    for sublist in L:
        name = sublist[1]
        if name not in d:
            d[name]=NameOb()
        d[name].add_record(sublist[0], sublist[2], sublist[3])

    for name, nameob in d.items():
        d[name] = nameob.get_as_list() 

    return d 


print(name_Index(None))
```